# Trying to start ripple effect on touch screens by "touchstart"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ripple

I'm using a jQuery plugin for ripple effect. **[Here](http://tinchop997.github.io/ripple-effect/)** is the link of the plugin.
The thing that I want is to trigger the effect with `touchstart` on touch devices to improve the experience on these devices. I tried replacing:

`mousedown` --> `touchstart`

`mouseup` --> `touchend`

`dragend` --> `touchleave`

but it didn't work at all and I have no idea what solution is.
**Can you modify the jQuery to trigger the effect with `touchstart`?**

Here is a snippet of the original code:

```js
// Get all the elements that requiere the effect
var rippleButton = document.querySelectorAll('[data-ripple-effect]'),
  i;

// The animation function
function rippleEffect(event) {
  // Getting the div that the effect is relative to
  var box = this.lastElementChild,
    x,

    // Creating the effect's div
    create = document.createElement('div'),

    // Getting the button's size, distance to top and left
    boxWidth = box.offsetWidth,
    boxHeight = box.offsetHeight,
    boxY = box.getBoundingClientRect().top,
    boxX = box.getBoundingClientRect().left,

    // Getting the mouse position
    mouseX = event.clientX,
    mouseY = event.clientY,

    // Mouse position relative to the box
    rippleX = mouseX - boxX,
    rippleY = mouseY - boxY,

    // Calculate distance to farest corner
    rippleWidth = boxWidth / 2 < rippleX ? rippleX : boxWidth - rippleX,
    rippleHeight = boxHeight / 2 < rippleY ? rippleY : boxHeight - rippleY,

      // Distance to the farest corner
    boxSize = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(rippleWidth, 2) +
                        Math.pow(rippleHeight, 2)),

    // Getting the type value for multiple ripples at the same time
    multi = this.getAttribute('data-multi-ripple'),

    // Getting the button computed style
    thisStyle = window.getComputedStyle(this);

  // Allowing multiple ripples at same time or not
  if (multi === 'no' || multi === 'false' || multi === '0') {
    this.removeEventListener('mousedown', rippleEffect);
  }

  // Creating and moving the effect div inside the button
  box.appendChild(create);

  // Ripple style (size, position, color and border-radius)
  create.classList.add('ripple-effect');
  create.style.height = 2 * boxSize + 'px';
  create.style.width = 2 * boxSize + 'px';
  create.style.top = mouseY - boxY - boxSize + 'px';
  create.style.left = mouseX - boxX - boxSize + 'px';
  box.style.borderTopLeftRadius =
    thisStyle.getPropertyValue('border-top-left-radius');
  box.style.borderTopRightRadius =
    thisStyle.getPropertyValue('border-top-right-radius');
  box.style.borderBottomLeftRadius =
    thisStyle.getPropertyValue('border-bottom-left-radius');
  box.style.borderBottomRightRadius =
    thisStyle.getPropertyValue('border-bottom-right-radius');
  setTimeout(function () {
    create.classList.add('ripple-effect-start');
  }, 0);

  // Delete animation function
  function removeChild() {
    create.classList.remove('ripple-effect-start');
    create.classList.add('ripple-effect-end');
    setTimeout(function () {
      box.removeChild(create);
    }, 500);
    window.removeEventListener('mouseup', removeChild);
    window.removeEventListener('dragend', removeChild);
    if (multi === 'no' || multi === 'false' || multi === '0') {
      box.parentElement.addEventListener('mousedown', rippleEffect);
    }
  }

  // Delete  div after animation finished
  window.addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
    x = false;
  });
  window.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
    x = true;
  });
  window.addEventListener('dragend', function () {
    x = true;
  });
  setTimeout(function () {
    if (x) {
      removeChild();
    } else {
      window.addEventListener('mouseup', removeChild);
      window.addEventListener('dragend', removeChild);
    }
  }, 600);
}

window.onload = function () {
  // Adding to all the elements the necesary div and the event listener to run
  // the animation
  for (i = 0; i < rippleButton.length; i += 1) {
    var create = document.createElement('div'),
      button = rippleButton[i];

    // Adding the listener to run the effect
    button.addEventListener('mousedown', rippleEffect);

    // Creating a div inside the mask-div to be the reference for the ripple
    // position
    rippleButton[i].appendChild(create);
    create.classList.add('ripple-effect-box');
  }
};
```

```css
/* ========================================================================= */
/* RIPPLE EFFECT =========================================================== */
/* ========================================================================= */

[data-ripple-effect] {
  position: relative; /* Setting the element relative for reference */
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

/* box which contains the ripple */
.ripple-effect-box {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(white, black);
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  -o-transform: scale(1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Ripple Effect style (background, border-radius, time) */
.ripple-effect {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  -moz-transition: all 500ms;
  -o-transition: all 500ms;
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms;
  transition: all 500ms;
  -moz-transform: scale(0);
  -ms-transform: scale(0);
  -o-transform: scale(0);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
}

.ripple-effect-start {
  opacity: 1;
  -moz-transform: scale(1.0);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.0);
  -o-transform: scale(1.0);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
  transform: scale(1.0);
}

.ripple-effect-end {
  opacity: 0;
  -moz-transform: scale(1.0);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.0);
  -o-transform: scale(1.0);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
  transform: scale(1.0);
}


.button {
background: #eee;
border: none;
outline: none;
padding: 8px 12px;
border-radius: 2px;
cursor: pointer;}
```

```html
<button class="button" data-ripple-effect data-multi-ripple="0">Ripple</button>
```

Comment: Take a look at JQuery Touch Punch - http://touchpunch.furf.com/

Comment: @nixkuroi I'm not using jQuery UI, my ripple effect starts with `mousedown` on all devices. I want it to be triggered with `mousedown` on non-touch and with `touchstart` on touch devices, like what we see on [material.io](http://material.io) side nav.

Comment: @nixkuroi any idea???

Comment: Have you tried just copying the mouse event lines of code, and adding in the desired touch events beneath them using the same code, but just replacing the mouse event name with the touch event name?

Comment: @nixkuroi Yeah, I copied it beneat the original code, then I remove every function containing `dragend` (the code still works). And I replaced `mousedown` with `touchstart` and `mouseup` with `touchend`, but after this it was not working.

Comment: Have you tried just adding them, without removing the other code?

Comment: @nixkuroi Yes, I've tried that too.